# Oh what a tangled Web tag we weave

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

While cleaning up untagged posts, I noticed we probably have some significant redundancy in our web related tags:

[image]

mobile web and web app are definitely fine, websites is a synonym of website design. I'm not sure which, if any, of the remaining tags are unique enough or if we should merge all of them into one or which would be the best.

Web is a bit more generic, which is a plus and a minus. Website design is by far the most popular. Website and webdesign can easily be synonymized to website-design, so I guess the real question is do we need "web" and "website design" and which do we keep if not?

---

Well that's confusing, Website and webdesign were already synonyms of Website Design so I've merged them and kept them as synonyms. Web is the only unaccounted for one.

Comment: I think that [web-app](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-app) is badly defined or badly used. On the last 5 questions, it's only relevant once.

Answer (score 1):

Skimming through the first 50 [web](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) questions, most (all?) of them appear to be about web design.  (One is about interpreting web research to inform the web design.  Keeping web research separate is the only reason I can think of to separate [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) from other web tags.)

There's a fairly high degree of overlap.  Of 135 total [web](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) questions, 29 are also tagged as [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design).  This suggests that the tags don't have different meanings (and that because people aren't sure which to use they use both).

Because [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) has by far the most questions of any of these tags, I support merging  [websites](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites),[webdesign](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webdesign),[website](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website), and [web](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) into [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design).

Comment: No need to blacklist, a synonym will mean anyone trying to use the tag will automatically be given the "right" tag (website design) tag instead. I agree with this solution though.